# Overriding default properties in Kafka MirrorMaker2

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am running a kafka cluster and replicating it to another cluster using Mirrormaker 2.0 as per the below documentation:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0

Specifically, I am running the below command to start my mirror maker:

```
./bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh ./config/mirror-maker.properties
```

I have lots of data in my source cluster and I am frequently running in timeout error. For this purpose I want to setup the below two properties:

```
buffer.bytes (default value 32 MB)
offset.flush.timout.ms (default value 5000)
```

I have tried to override these properties into my mirror maker properties, but the default value is being picked. Any suggestions on how I can override these default values?

Comment: Have you tried the prefixes for how Kafka Connect, in general, allows you to set those?  `consumer.` or `consumer.override.` (similar for producer)?